# Does ros need a high performance gpu?

Tags: ros, opencv, gpu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to make a robot like turtlebot,with kinect and a netbook,turtlebot's netbook has a discrete graphic.
I want to do 2d or 3d slam and navigation,then is opencv's image processing,does the netbook need a high performance gpu?Or I just need a good cpu?Atom N570 can be ok?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32560/does-ros-need-a-high-performance-gpu?/) by [Starsky Wong](https://answers.ros.org/users/2245/starsky-wong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-04-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For *visualization*, particularly of large point clouds (like are generated by the Kinect), you will need a pretty serious GPU.

Otherwise, you don't need a GPU at all. OpenCV, PCL, etc. are CPU libraries (although both have some experimental GPU features), as are all of the various ROS tools. I don't know enough about Atom CPUs to tell you if that particular one is enough; I can tell you that (save visualization), I've used pretty old netbooks with a lot of success.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Starsky Wong](https://answers.ros.org/users/2245/starsky-wong/) on 2012-04-26**:
Thank you!I think I'll do visualization in another PC,but needs data transmission.

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-04-28**:
If you'll be transmitting the point clouds wirelessly, you'll need a pretty serious pipe. PCL has some point-cloud-compression stuff that helps. (Basically, point clouds are lots of data; you have to pay somewhere).